# Can't get in Central Administration

Tags: authentication, central-administration

Apparently within the last 3-4 weeks we lost our ability to get into Central Administration.  Now when I or the other SA tries to get to the URL with port it asks us to authenticate again and doesn't take our credentials.  (Directly on server, as we've always done it.)  Tried our domain accounts and local admin account on the box.

We were trying to get in there because some Sharepoint database on C: exploded in size the last week or so and filled up the drive and the setting is in... Central Administration.  It's awesome troubleshooting an interface to be able to get in to troubleshoot the initial problem.

No changes have been made on this server as the departing SharePoint guy apparently left them in a test OU with no GPOs, it doesn't have firewall/McAfee... Not sure what could have changed.

Appreciate any advice.

Comment: After you fixed that CentralAdmin-Problem, you should move your Databases off the C: drive. It's only a matter of time when this will repeat.

Comment: Definitely.  After seeing all of the comments in SharePoint Health Analyzer I am trying very hard to not become the new SharePoint admin...  I have no experience with SharePoint and this system appears to have many things that need to be be looked at.  On a side note, I got CA back but not quite sure exactly how.  Last change I made was setting CA App Pool identity to Network Service then back to service account. I could then get back in.  Could be coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

Is the URL the same as the server’s hostname?

If not, then you’re experiencing the classic NTLM loopback issue.

Access CA from a different host, add the hostname to the backconnectionhostnames registry setting or disable loopback checking entirely (not recommended).  See
https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/926642/error-message-when-you-try-to-access-a-server-locally-by-using-its-fqd for instructions on the second (Method 1) and third (Method 2) options.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Address is http://hostname:port.  I even had taken some notes and screenshots last time I was in here so I know I'm not crazy...

Comment: But is the hostname the same as the server’s name?

Comment: Yes, it's the same.

Comment: Hmm.  Then loopback isn’t the issue.  It normally manifests in repeated prompts for credentials before sending a 401 back even if they’re correct.

Comment: But that behavior is very similar to what I'm seeing.  Multiple prompts with known credentials, but then I get a 400 bad request error; page cannot be found.

Comment: It could still be it.  Have you tried accessing the URL from off the server?

Comment: Yeah, I tried url:port and ip:port also resulting in the same behavior.

Comment: From a different host?  If it’s happening from another host then loopback checking isn’t the issue.

Comment: I get TLS error going to hostname & url, and page cannot be displayed after multiple cred prompts when connecting by IP from the SharePoint SQL server.

Comment: What’s the Access Mapping for CA?

Comment: Sorry, our SharePoint guy quit a few months ago so I'm learning on the job.  Let me Google how to check that.

Comment: Can you access SharePoint on the server via the Management Shell?

Comment: I can open the SharePoint Powershell, yes.

Comment: No errors?  What you may be able to do is remove and reprovision CA if it’s “broken”.  You’ll need to Google the procedure.  But first check if you can use the shell to do what you needed to do in CA first.

Comment: Okay.  Appreciate your time!

Comment: Good luck and have fun.